# Python merging multiple csv files

Tags: python, string, byte

So I tried to follow a tutorial to merge all my csv files. I made the mistake of following a python 2 tutorial while have python 3 installed. Then I tried to change it to python 3.

Now I am stuck with the following code.

```
import glob
import csv

csvfiles = glob.glob('walk\*')
wf = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'wb'), delimiter = ',')

for files in csvfiles:
    rd = csv.reader(open(files, 'r'), delimiter = ',')
    next(rd)
    for row in rd:
        print (row)
        wf.writerow(row)
```

With this code I get the error: 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'' . So I googled that error and found that I had to open my files as a text file using 'rt' in stead of r. That is not solving the problem unfortunately.

Comment: use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

Comment: so start over with a new tutorial using panda's ?

Comment: it ain't that hard if you ask me, you have to learn only [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to work with CSV files

Comment: @raviraja (and everyone): could you PLEASE stop posting comments and answers basically saying "use panda" each and everytime you see the word or tag "csv" in a question ? Panda uses the stdlib's `csv` module so it won't add anything for such kind of operations, except a huge overhead. Panda's goal is to make complex computations / transformations on tabular data, not to replace the stdlib's `csv` module.

Comment: i have suggested him/her to use pandas because it's easier for a beginner.

Comment: That is indeed a good point Bruno. But the reason I suggested it is because it provides an easier to use interface to the csv module, and that is what this person was struggling with. Of course I only will suggest it as a recommendation after providing the relevant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're opening output.csv as a byte file with "wb" and trying to write text to it. Try just "w" in line 5. Alternatively, maybe check out doing this using pandas. Pandas has pretty nice I/O and you can pretty easily concatenate your csv files together before resaving them.